# Try to save favorite button state in app Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have an app that i get a list from my api. so in this list i want ti choose some object that its a favorite objects, so i want to save the selected items when i navigate back. but i choose items and when i go back and come to page again, All favorites button are empty. can you provide me some code from example?
here is my code:

```
return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 1, childAspectRatio: 3 / 1.5),
      itemCount: widget.item.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        persist() async{
          setState(() {
            widget.item[index].liked = !widget.item[index].liked;
          });
          
        }
        return InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PropertyDetailsPage(),
                settings: RouteSettings(
                    arguments: widget.item[index]
                )
            ));
          },
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.04,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              child: Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed:persist,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          color:widget.item[index].liked ? Colors.red : Colors.grey[500],
                        )),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 15,
                        )),
                        Text(widget.item[index].Price,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "IranSans",
                              fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IzEJ.gif)

Comment: Save where exactly? In a global variable list, back-end i.e Firebase, shared preferences?

Comment: shared preferences bro @krumpli

Comment: @krumpli can you provide me example please?

Comment: There are loads of examples within a simple google search

Comment: example on my code!! @krumpli

Comment: were you able to achieve this?